# proving a property of Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field, $S = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ the polynomial ring, $m = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $I$ a homogeneous ideal contained in $m^2$. Define $R = S/I$. For $p \in \mathbb{N}$ we say that $R$ is $p$-regular if $H_m^q(R)_{p-q} = 0$ for all $q>0$ and $H_m^0(R)_r=0$ for all $r \ge 0$. I want to prove that if $R$ is $p$-regular and $p' >p$ then $R$ is also $p'$-regular.

I have proved that not all elements of $m$ in $R / H_m^0(R)$ are zero-divisors. In particular some $x_i$ is not a zero-divisor, say $i=1$. Then $x_1^d$ is not a zero divisor for any positive $d$. This gives an exact sequence
$0 \rightarrow \frac{R}{H_m^0(R)} (-d) \stackrel{x_1^d}{\rightarrow} \frac{R}{H_m^0(R)} \rightarrow \frac{R}{H_m^0(R)+(a)} \rightarrow 0$.

> Question 1: How can i use this sequence to show that $H_m^q(R)_{p+d-q} = 0$?

If i take the long exact cohomology sequence corresponding to the exact sequence above, i encounter a difficulty:

> Question 2: How does $H_m^q(R/H_m^0(R))$ relate to $H_m^q(R)$? Intuitively, it seems that these two are equal for $q>0$ but how can we prove that if this is the case?

The answer to question 2 would be positive if $H_m^0(R)$ is a *injective module.
This motivates

> Question 3: Is $H_m^0(R)$ an injective module in the category of graded modules?

Comment: 2) For any $m$-torsion module $M$ (that is, $\Gamma_m(M)=M$) we have $H_m^i(M)=0$ for all $i>0$. For an arbitrary $R$-module $N$ we get $H_m^i(\Gamma_m(N))=0$ for all $i>0$, and therefore $H_m^i(N)\simeq H^i(N/\Gamma_a(N))$.

Comment: 3) is not true in general. Let $(R,m)$ be an Artinian local ring. You may want to consider a trivial grading on $R$. Then $H^0_m (R) = R$, but not every Artinian local ring is Gorenstein which is a consequence of having finite injective dimension.

Comment: @user26857: Is that in view of Theorem 3.5.7a) in B&H, since every $m$-torsion module $M$ has dimension zero?

Comment: This follows from some basic observations: the local cohomology can be computed from injective resolutions, and an $m$-torsion module has an $m$-torsion injective resolution (just note that $\Gamma_m(I)$ is injective if $I$ is injective). But, of course, if you like you could also use that $H_m^i(M)=0$ for $i>d=\dim M$.

Comment: @user26857: Let me see if i understand your argument correctly. 1)If $I$ is injective, then $\Gamma_m(I)$ is inside $I$ and the injective hull of $\Gamma_m(I)$ in $I$ is a maximal essential extension of $\Gamma_m(I)$ in $I$. By applying the definition of maximal essential extension, we see that $\Gamma_m(I)$ coincides with its injective hull and so it is injective. Correct? 2) If $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow I_0 \rightarrow I_1 \cdots$ is an injective resolution of $M$, by left-exactness of $\Gamma_m$ we have that $M$ is embedded in $\Gamma_m(I_0)$. Now $I_0/M$ is embedded in $I_1$...

Comment: @user26857:...But $\Gamma_m(I_0)/M$ is embedded in $I_0/M$ and so $\Gamma_m(I_0)/M$ is embedded in $I_1$. Again by left exactness of $\Gamma_m$ we see that $\Gamma_m(I_0)/M$ is embedded in $\Gamma_m(I_1)$. Continuing in this way, we have an injective resolution $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow \Gamma_m(I_0) \rightarrow \Gamma_m(I_1) \rightarrow \cdots...$. Correct?